# Populate BaseAdapter from web

Tags: android, stream, adapter

I've a JSON array like this:
[{"usename":"user", "user_pic":"picture", "photo":"http://hfhfhfhhfh.jpg", "timestamp":"10-09-10"} {"username":"user2", ..........}]
I've 10 JSONObject in this array, and I want use it for populate a stream with:
Avatar - Nickname
Photo 
Timestamp
Is a stream of my application, I want have the latest post of other user.
How can I populate the stream?
I think i could use a baseadapter is correct?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a BaseAdapter or an ArrayAdapter depending on your implementation.
But you would have to overwritye the default implementation to show your list items as you want them to be displayed.
You may also check the listview examples here.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html.

Basically what you might want in your situation is.

1. Have a progress dialog or some other indicator just before you start downloading json.
2. Download json.
3. parse it and Convert it into your list of objects[probably Arraylist]
4. Pass this list on to your ListView Adapter. This was your main issue and you need to overwrite the BaseAdapter to create your own adapter.
   Here is an example from google search
   http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327.
   You may need to search for more example if you need more help.
5. Once you pass the list to your adapter you will need to close the progress dialog.